# Vim でのカレントディレクトリ以下のファイル検索について

Tags: vim, sublimetext, atom-editor

atom や Sublime Text での <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> みたいなファイル検索を
Vim でやりたいのですが、どのようにすればいいか分からないです。

NERDTree も入れていて grep も入れて
[ここ](http://qiita.com/masa2sei/items/94f6d89bbd0c2ffcd53b)とか[ここ](http://qiita.com/yuku_t/items/0c1aff03949cb1b8fe6b)とか見ながら苦戦しましたが
`grep` だとファイル越しに特定の単語が入ってるファイルを見つけてくれる？ような感じだと思うので
少し違うのかな？というか、いまいち `grep` も自分の思ったように操作できてないのだと思うのですが…。

`:e` で `:e ./**/*.html` みたいにすると新しく `*.html` が作成されてしまったりするのですが
これはどういう事なのでしょうか…。

例えば今自分がプロジェクトのルートディレクトリにいるとして
`app/views/layouts/application.html` の `application.html` を探したいとしたときに

`application*` みたいな単語で検索すると、それにひっかかるファイルがいくつか出てきて
その中から、自分の開きたいファイルを選んで開く

というような動作がしたいのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか…。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) プラグインをお薦めします。
カレントディレクトリ以下のファイルをキーワードであいまい検索し、開くことができます。
この手のプラグインはFuzzyFinderとも言われ、他にも色々あるようですが、ctrlpは必要十分な機能があり、設定も少なく、分かりやすいプラグインです。

- ctrlp.vimの参考サイト
  https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim
  http://qiita.com/oahiroaki/items/d71337fb9d28303a54a8
  http://mattn.kaoriya.net/software/vim/20111228013428.htm
- NERDTreeやctrlp.vimを使ったファイルの開き方の参考動画
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XrHk3xjYsw

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Tab</kbd>キーを押すことでワイルドカードに当てはまるファイル名を補完できます。

`:e **/application*<Tab>`

Comment: そうそう、プラグイン入れなくても`:e`や`:find`で`**`使って`<Tab>`や`<C-D>`押せば実現できるんですよね。(`:h starstar`)
あと、`<Tab>`の前の`*`はなくてもイケます。

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim

CtrlP を入れて `<C-P>` をタイプすれば期待通りになると思います。

Answer (score 1):

[Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) という選択肢もありますね。インストール後 `:Unite file` で目的の挙動となります。ついでに言うと Git リポジトリ内ならば `:Unite file/git` で Git リポジトリでトラックされているファイルから探すこともできます。速度面の問題から自分はこちらを多用しております。

Unite は CtrlP と比較した際に設定が様々あり煩わしい反面、様々なことが統一されたインターフェイスで実行できるという利点があります（[作者以外が作成したプラグイン一覧](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/wiki/unite-plugins)）。例えば自分で定義した Vim のキーマッピングを一覧表示することや編集中のバッファからマッチする行を検索するなども同じインターフェイスで実行できます。

あと作者がVimプラグインを精力的に開発している日本人なので質問しやすいという利点もあります（笑。